# Error in getElementsByTagName

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to read in a html file, and then only display certain parts on the page.

I have currently read in the file using AJAX and the requestData.js file.  I can then alert out the whole page using that html variable I have created and that works fine.

However it is then when I try and get all the `<p>` Tags (or any other tag doesn't work), that it comes up with this error.

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'html.getElementsByTagName("div")')

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="requestData.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">

    function refresh(xmlhttp){
        var html = xmlhttp.responseText;
        var ps = html.getElementsByTagName("p");
    }

</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>

<input type = "submit" onclick = "requestData('home.html', refresh)">

</html>
```

Comment: `responseText` is a string.  You need to "parse" it to be able to call DOM methods on it.

Comment: Thanks.  Can I ask how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an element and set its content to your HTML. This will give you the ability to run `getElementsByTagName()` on it:

```
var html = xmlhttp.responseText;

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = html;

var ps = div.getElementsByTagName("p");
```

Comment: I just posted the same answer! :-D

Answer (score 1):

`responseText` is a string.  You need to "parse" it to be able to call DOM methods on it.

One way is to make a "fake" `<div>` then append the string to it.

```
var html = xmlhttp.responseText;
var parse = document.createElement('div');
parse.innerHTML = html;

var ps = parse.getElementsByTagName("p");
```

Answer (score -1):

html var its just string, use jQuery Framework for parsing it :)
Like this `jQuery(html).Find('p');`

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a javascript way to do this?  I swear I've done it before in Javascript?

Comment: Why would jQuery be required for this? @Jack: jQuery *is* JavaScript, *anything* that jQuery can do, JavaScript can do (by definition).

Comment: Im not saying, that jQuery is not JavaScript(O_o).

Comment: As to the latter sentence, my bad: I forgot to target the recipient.